# Looking for a new SandBox

Tags: game

I own and have played through 100% of the stories in Far Cry 3 and 4, GTA 4 and 5 and Skyrim. I also have found myself getting in literally hundreds of hours on these games and love their open, sandbox style worlds, but alas, I'm looking for something new.

Are there any other sandbox style games that would be as large and/or detailed a these?

Genre, producer or platform do not much matter, and I'm also not looking for opinions, just games that fit this particular style of a loose story and a LARGE sandbox to play in.

Any O/S, platform is welcome, as are all styles (MMORPG, etc.)

Comment: Which o/s, or is browser acceptable? If a specific o/s, which you don't have, would you be willing to play the perfect game in a virtual machine? Free, or do you have a budget? The more information that you give us, the more we can help you.

Comment: Single player only? Or are MMORPGs welcome?

Comment: I updated the question to answer your questions. Any platform or O/S is welcome. Single player, MMORPG, doesn't matter.

Comment: Good (+1). We are encouraging people to ask better questions (not that yours was particularly bad, in comparison with some ;-). Giving more requirements _might_ seem restricting, but it also aids us greatly and makes sure that you do not get inappropriate recommendations. I'm not much of a gamer, but I do like all 4X, especially the Civilization series.

Comment: How about Minecraft? You do get a _very large_ sandbox with that game. ;)

Comment: Perhaps try the older Elder scroll games, like Oblivion and Morrowind. Have never played the first three myself, but if you want something HUGE and are willing to go all nostalgic, you might want to check out the freely downloadable Daggerfall (the map of Morrowind is supposedly just 0.01% the size of Daggerfall's map).

Comment: Also, you might want to check out this list: http://www.pcgamesn.com/15-best-sandbox-games-pc

Comment: Fallout 3 and Fallout New Vegas

Comment: @BrownRedHawk what about `Just Cause 3` and `ProtoType` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going for an MMORPG suggestion. I play [Lord of The Rings Online](http://www.lotro.com/en). The world is based on [Middle Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth) from Tolkien's writings, and the story takes place within the period of the Lord of The Rings books.

It's especially fun if you are a Tolkien fan, and if you have a group of friends to form a fellowship with. It has a large number of quests and deeds, and basically anything you kill awards you with deed points, in-game currency, and craft resources.

In addition, the game features an optional main quest line (called Epic Quest), which involves you and your friends helping the Fellowship of The Ring during various stages of their journey.

You are able to create multiple characters of different races and classes, buy a house, join a kinship, participate in raids on high level monsters, etc... It's also possible to play as one of the bad guys. You could easily spend hundreds of hours there, and make some new friends.

The first few regions in the game are free-to-play, but later patches require a subscription. It runs on PC

Answer (score 2):

Just Cause 2 is definitely one of my all-time favorite sandbox games.

I'm not sure if you wanted details about the games or just game names and you will do the research yourself. Anyway, in Just Cause 2 you rack up something called Chaos points, and this is the only way you can get to your next storyline mission, and yes, you literally get those points by... Well... Causing chaos. There are *so* many vehicles and settings in this game it's difficult to believe. There are sunny island getaways, snowy mountaintops, and a nightclub on an airship... Yep. You can also do something called a "stunt jump" on all vehicles in the game which involves you jumping out of the vehicle while it's moving and shooting stuff. You also have a grappling hook that you use in a variety of ways across the game, for instance once I was really bored and hooked a guy up to a 747 airliner and took off. This game is ridiculous, and in a good way!

http://www.geforce.com/games-applications/pc-games/just-cause2/screenshots

Check out this gallery and go play this game! Peace!